# Here-document with cat

Tags: linux, cat, here-document

I am new to Linux, shell scripting, and I'm trying to learn the fundamentals. I am currently on the redirection chapter, where here-documents are being explained. I could not really understand how the code below works in conjunction with the `cat` command. If some one can please tell me?

```
cat << EOF
line1 
line2
line3
EOF
```

I very well understand how `<< EOF` works. The keyword denotes the end of input. My question is; `cat` takes filename(s) as input stream; so that it can print its content on output stream. How does above work **internally**? We are not specifying filename anywhere. Does the shell create internally some temporary file and give it to `cat`? I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When `cat` is not given a filename on the command line (or if the filename is just `-`), then it switches to reading from its standard input.

That means that with

```
cat <<END
something something
END
```

`cat` will notice that it was not given a filename and will proceed to read from the here-document, which is arriving on its standard input stream.

You can get `cat` to read from both its standard input and from a file with

```
cat - filename <<END
something something
END
```

This will cause the contents of the here-document to be concatenated with the contents of `filename`.  If the order of the arguments was `filename -` then that would be the order that the data would be concatenated too.

Note that `-` is not special to the shell in any way, and is interpreted as "standard input" specifically by the `cat` utility (and a few others).  If you have an actual file called `-` that you need to run `cat` on, use `cat ./-`, i.e. specify the filename with a path.

---

For all purposes, you can think of feeding a here-document directly into a utility as a shorthand for creating a temporary file and then invoking the utility with that attached to the standard input stream:

```
printf 'some contents' >tmpfile
utility <tmpfile
rm -f tmpfile
```

Here-documents might not actually be implemented this way (it may be a FIFO (named pipe)), but that's not an entirely incorrect way of thinking about it.

Reading the `bash` sources, it seems as if that particular shell implements here-documents by creating a temporary file using the `mkstemp()` library function if it's available, otherwise it tries to create a random filename to write to.  The contents of the document is then written to that file and the data is provided on the standard input of whatever it is that's reading it, just as if it came from a file, redirected with `<`.  See `redir.c` and `lib/sh/tmpfile.c` in the `bash` source distribution.

Comment: Good to have that insight!. Folks like you really helps! in learning :)